Generating access token for Youtube Reporting API
I was invited to a YouTube channel. To accept the invitation, I had to create a channel. Now, I have two channels.
After generating the OAUTH2 token, if I list the channel, it shows the default channel I created, not the invited one.
I am required to list the jobs in the invited channel.
How can I do this, please?
The following are the steps:

I received an invite to join the YouTube channel. Let's say "Channel X."
It was mentioned that I had to create a channel before joining it. Therefore, I created "Channel Y".
I use Google OAuth Playground to generate the access token.
I select the following scopes:

YouTube Analytics API v2
YouTube Data API v3
YouTube Reporting API v1

Under configurations, I use my own OAuth Credentials.
On clicking Authorize API's, it suggest to pick the google account. I select my google account.
Then in place of listing the channels, it again list google account to select. I select mine.
I get the access token but it is specific to the channel I created "Channel Y". I need access token for "Channel X".

Thank you

please edit your question and include [example]

Thank you, Linda. I added the steps I am following. Please let me know if you need any further information.

YouTube apis are channel based.  So when you run the authorize script it shows you a list of channels that you can pick to authorize the application with.
You will then only have access to that channel.
Run the app again and grant it access to the correct channel.

Hi Linda, Thank you for the input. When I authorize the script, it first asks me to select a Google account. I choose my Google account; then, in place of listing two channels associated with my Google account, it lists my Google account again. Selecting it generates the token, but it is for the Channel I created, and I wanted the token for the invited channel.
